# Displaying columns based on the table parameter selected

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an adhoc report that I am doing. The user is to be able to select a table from the database and then select the columns that they want to be displayed. This is the code that I have and the parameters.

```
SELECT 
    name, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME  
FROM 
    sys.tables
INNER JOIN  
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ON TABLE_NAME = name
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = @TableName <--multiselect drop down
    AND COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName <--multiselect drop down
```

My question is how do I make the columns on the report so that it will show the corresponding column names based on the selection. some tables have 4 columns, some have 30. I have seen how to make the columns visibility hidden based on selection but there are 278 columns that I would have to do this to, there has to be a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that you *either* use the SQL Server specific `sys.*` system catalog views (like `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`), or then you use the ANSI/ISO standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views - but don't mix the two. Pick one, stick with it.

Comment: Are you using a stored procedure to execute the above query? @R Arriaga

Comment: Not as of now, I'm still trying to figure out if i need to or not.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways.

**Method 1 : Passing table name as parameter and Column names as Comma Separated Values**

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100) = 'Tablename'
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(100) = 'Column1,Column2'

SELECT 
    name, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME  
FROM 
    sys.tables
INNER JOIN  
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ON TABLE_NAME = name
WHERE 
TABLE_NAME = @TableName
AND COLUMN_NAME IN
(
    -- Convert Comma Separated Values to rows
    SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'-','.'),1) 'Columns' 
    FROM  
    (
         SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@ColumnName, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data              
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
```

**Method 2 : Passing table name as parameter and Column names in a temporary table**

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100) = 'Tablename'    

SELECT 
    name, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME  
FROM 
    sys.tables
INNER JOIN  
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ON TABLE_NAME = name
WHERE 
TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
AND COLUMN_NAME IN
(
    -- Consider you are inserting the column names to a temporary table before executing this query
    SELECT COLS FROM TEMPTABLE
)
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? @R Arriaga

Comment: I was more asking how do i map the columns in the tablix to display the variable amount of columns. Thanks